# symbol issue in php

Tags: php, html

is there any way to convert this symbol – in php

```
    $payment_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $currencyCode = get_option('wpoupon_currency');
    $countryCode = get_option('wpoupon_country');
    $payPalId = get_option('wpoupon_payment_email');

    $notifyLink = getPermalink('&mode=notifyurl&user_id='.$current_user->ID,$itemID);
    $returnLink = getPermalink('&mode=returnurl',$itemID);
    $cancelLink = getPermalink('&mode=cancel',$itemID);

    $form_custom = '';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'. $payPalId .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'. htmlspecialchars($itemName) .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'. $itemID .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'. $itemPrice .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="'. $quantity .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="'. $currencyCode .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="'. $notifyLink .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to get your Coupon!">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'. $returnLink .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="'. $cancelLink .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="'. $countryCode .'">';
    $form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">';

    echo '<form action="'. $payment_url .'" method="post" name="payment" id="payment">'. $form_custom .'</form>';
```

because when this hidden value is submitting to paypal like

Charisma Beauty **â€“** Save 51% Buy

is there any way to solve this issue

so i use

```
$form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'. htmlspecialchars($itemName) .'">';

now its showing in paypal as **"Charisma Beauty &#8211; Save 51% Buy Now"**
```

Comment: that is an `Microsoft Word` symbol and is used mainly in MS Word. You should change it to a normal `-`

Comment: its client requirment. if u ask me i won't prefer to use symbols in titles.

Comment: It is not a Microsoft Word symbol, it is an [en dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash). You could try using `&ndash;` instead of `&#8211` though Paypal may not accept that either.

Comment: @JohnLawrence £ is showing in paypal as **Charisma Beauty Â£ Save 51% Buy Now**

Answer (score 1):

Use `urlencode` before submitting your data to paypal.

```
$form_custom .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'. urlencode($itemName) .'">';
```

Comment: now its looking like .. **Charisma+Beauty+%26%238211%3B+Save+**